Can't post question (Safari problem?)
I'm trying to post a question to SO and I'm hitting a weird brick wall.  After typing in a title and a body, and selecting a few tags, I click the "Review question" button as usual, and... nothing happens.  Nothing at all.
I've tried using two different versions of Safari (details below), on two different Macs, connecting via three different networks.  I've tried posting to several different SO and SE sites.  I've restarted the browser multiple times, logged out of and then back in to SO, cleared all cookies and other history, etc., etc.  No-go every time.
Only by using a completely different browser on a completely different computer (at work) am I having any luck posting this question to meta.  Although, in response to a comment, I later tried some other browsers on the nonworking Macs, and those browsers do work.
I have definitely posted questions using Safari to SO in the past, and I've confirmed that I can still post answers.  (Nor have I made any changes that I know of to Safari's configuration.)  So the problem is somehow peculiar to posting questions, or perhaps more specifically to reviewing questions.
Has anything changed recently?  Does anyone have suggestions on anything else I could check, or try?
The browsers and OSes I've tried are:



OS
OS version
Browser
Browser version
Status




MacOS
Ventura 13.0
Safari
16.1
hangs


MacOS
Ventura 13.0
Firefox
114.0.1
works


MacOS
High Sierra 10.13.6
Safari
11.1.2
hangs


MacOS
High Sierra 10.13.6
Chrome
116.0.5845.187
works


Windows
Windows 10 Enterprise v 22H2
Firefox
115.10.0esr
works




You mention connecting via 3 different networks and not finding success, but then mention it works at your workplace... is that a 4th network or one of the 3? Also, do you have any user scripts in play on your personal devices that might not be installed on your work computer? What browser did you use at work where you were able to post?

@TylerH Yes, the work network was one of the ones that didn't work with the personal Mac.  Work computer is Firefox on Windows.  No customizations on either of the personal Macs that I would think would affect posting questions to Stack -- or that have in the past.

Have you tested a non-Safari browser on any of the Macs? That would help determine if it's browser-specific or OS-specific.

Please provide in each case that you tested, your OS, OS version, browser (assumed to be Safari), and browser version.

@TylerH Looks like it may be browser-specific.

@Makyen Details added.
